# How to append short url to specific external links

Tags: query-string, shortlink

I'm trying to find a way to pass on the page ID as a string for certain links.

For example, any link that starts with http://forms.woo.com/ will have

" ?pageurl='http://example.com/?p=1234' " added to it. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118823/check-if-url-has-certain-string-with-php

Check if the url has your string, then spit something different out based on it. Perhaps something like...

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (false !== strpos($url,'forms.woo.com')) {
    echo '?pageurl=' . home_url() . get_the_ID(); // there's your page id url
} else {
    the_permalink(); // plain old permalink
}
```